# What level of technical skills/expertise is required for implementing CAS SSO?

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, cas, moodle

I am in a process of integrating several websites/content management tools to try out some of my ideas. Over the past couple of months, I have discovered tons of very helpful stuff, and it's great. I'm setting everything up just fine. To name a few it's: phpwebsite, moodle, livezilla, etc.

The problem is that I am doing everything myself and do lack technical knowledge.
I do have a strong programming background from way back then, which is no longer applicable. However, I seem to be managing do dig up HTML, PHP and JavaScript codes more or less OK, and things move forward pretty well.

Now it came to the need to implement SSO between a few of my systems. I like what I read about CAS, but the more I read the scarier it sounds:). I feel that I lack way too much technical expertise to be able to implement it myself. It looks like that it is not just simple logica installation and configuration as with most of the things I delt in a past two month, but kind overly complicated.

Should I risk it? What problems am I gonna face?
All the discussions I have been able to find so far are way to technical, not user friendly at all.
Please help me to build up some courage:)

Thanks,
Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing very well, there are many people ready to help you. Take a chance and you will learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least remove the burdeon of installing the CAS server by using the cloud provider: http://www.casinthecloud.com (free servers are available for tests). For all the integrated applications, it's still up to you, but it should be in your technology using the right CAS client.

Answer (score 0):

There is demo implementation [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Demo),

Hope that helps